# ¿como comparar arreglo de cadenas en c?

Tags: array, c, string

Tengo un arreglo de cadenas como el siguiente:
`char *names[] = { "Pedro", "Jose", "Ana", "Pedro" }`
Deseo comparar los elementos del arreglo y obtener los que son iguales en este caso Pedro.
Esto es lo que he intentado

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++){
        // printf("%i: %s\n", i + 1, names[i]);
        
        if(strcmp(names[i], "Pedro") == 0){
            printf("%s El nombre homonimo es", names[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Actualmente en el if estoy quemando el nombre de pedro que al comparar con los elementos del arreglo me devuelve que el nombre existe, pero como puedo hacerlo dinámicamente recorriendo los nombres que tengo en mi arreglo`names`, sin necesidad de quemarlo como lo estoy haciendo.
¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?
**gracias de antemano**,

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? El procedimiento no es muy diferente del que harías para un arreglo de números. Te doy una pista, puedes ayudarte con [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) para comparar 2 strings.

Comment: @Mateo ya actualice mi pregunta, gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer el mismo procedimiento para cada nombre. Con un for que comienza por el siguiente elemento al actual, de lo contrario se compararía con sí mismo. Además evitas comparar elementos que ya han sido comparados.

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < sizeA; j++){
        if(strcmp(names[i], names[j]) == 0){
            printf("El nombre homonimo es %s\n", names[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##bVBBTsMwELz7FaugSk5TCFxJi9QDF07cIQfjOM2G2q7s9EKVV/EEHhbWCY4IYg6e3dXO7Mjy@iDlMFyhkcdzpWDruwrtTfPAfo8cmkOYMTQdaIGGpxfGgCAb4WBthFb@pYQdXCB5VpWzyQaSJ@tV4L0RgeZ56KEvRn0w9Pih9qQNbGs@mqWQxz6cWKfFdK@2jgcN0v5tQbSd5FRmGYWCH@Q5nCh1V/Nkhfew8q@GTiNkcLeBKS6WaTHvR9@WfMetgsrZu114j7lrTt8i9YlHs2jblinsKNwfQUBM9HgEY/WbU9BY/fVpUFtQPob8J10EScT7ctyzZTW9TnVnZ@iHWD8M3w).